# How to copy image in Clipboard from drawable folder in android?

Tags: java, android

How to copy image in Clipboard from drawable folder in android ?

I mean copy image from drawable folder in Clipboard and paste anywhere.
Plese Help me.....

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Sir actually I am set images in third party Emoji keyboard so I want to copy image and paste anywhere , Click on image in Keyboard, please rply...Sir                                                                                                          myClipboard=(ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);       Integer image = R.drawable.img1;                                                       String text = String.valueOf(image);                                                   myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text); myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy the drawable image to sdcard you the below code.

You can do something like this,

```
    if (isSdPresent()) { // to check is sdcard mounted
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
            bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
            Bitmap bbicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "FolderName";
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File(extStorageDirectory);
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            File file = new File(wallpaperDirectory,"icon.png");
                     //to get resource name getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.icon);

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bbicon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            }
            } else {

            }
```

to check SDCard

```
public boolean isSdPresent() {
        return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
        android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it. Simply because Android clipboard doesn't support this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html).
The only things that you can keep in clipboard are: text, uri and intent.

Comment: myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                Integer image = R.drawable.img1;
                String text = String.valueOf(image);

                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);

Comment: This type Clipboard copied image but how to change clipdata string to Integer on pasting time ?   Please rply.....Sir

Comment: It won't work either. Because you just copied id of your image to clipboard. You keep unique id of image for your app that is not accessible outside. 
You can use it inside your app (but it is not a good idea) but it won't work anywhere else.

Comment: @SaurabhBhardwaj Integer.parseInt("1234"); but it is not a good idea

Comment: Sir actually I am set images in third party Emoji keyboard so I want to copy image and paste anywhere , Click on image in Keyboard, please rply...Sir